# How to work with TranslateAnimation in android?

Tags: android

I have moved the button from left to right using TranslateAnimation but after that button click listiner is not working for new location .

Answer (score 2):

Your actual button position is not changed when you use `TranslateAnimation`. It only updates transformation matrix for `Canvas` which is used to draw the button. So your button stands on the same location and dispatch touch events from the original area and is only drawn at the new location.

Comment: so in the end of the your animation you just have to set your new position to button.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `setFillAfter(true)` in code or `android:fillAfter` in xml.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android:fillAfter

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter(boolean)

there is an other solution here using animation on end event and setting the layout of the object.

http://pastebin.com/5dwzdJjG

On the other hand you can use two buttons one is your current one and the second one is placed the last place of the animation and invisible until the end of the animation, in the end of the animation just set invisible the first one and visible the second one.